# set a timeout and error message on my script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, openssl

I have a script that im trying to create an error message and timeout for if the openssl takes to long. Here is the script. Can anyone help me? I'm a little lost.

```
FILENAME=$1
while read -r ip; do
 echo "${ip}"
 echo -n | openssl s_client -connect "${ip}:443" -showcerts 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | openssl x509 -noout -dates

done < <(cut -d "," -f2 $FILENAME | tail -n +2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `timeout` from gnu core utils package([manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout))
Maybe do something like:

```
while read -r ip; do
 timeout [timeout duration] [your ssl command]

 if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
  echo FAIL
 else
  echo OK
 fi
done
```